# Does Gym defending pokemons automatically get kicked out for a specific condition without getting invaded?

Tags: pokemon-go

I live in a small town where exists 6 Gyms and 18 Pokestops. Since a week I have been noticing that 2 of those 6 gyms are malfunctioning, or maybe I am wrong...

Now let's come to the main point...

So story of 5 days ago, I captured all of the 6 gyms. So today 4 of the 6 Pokemons got kicked out.
Out of the 4 gyms from which my pokemons got kicked, 2 of the gyms are being controlled by another team and the rest of the 2 gyms are empty. For the rest of the 2 empty gyms, I doubt that had someone invaded it, he would have left his pokemon in it, but the rest 2 gyms remained empty .

Today is not the first time when those 2 out of 6 gyms malfunctioned it happened to me a couple of times

(Both of the malfunctioning gyms are newly transformed).

So, is it a gym glitch or someone is secretly invading the gym without leaving a pokemon to defend?

Or

Is it some unknown condition being met, the Pokemons are getting kicked out ?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see if you are passing by in a bus you might just throw in a battle to kick the Pokemon out, but by the time it’s done, they are too far to put one in. I just don’t get why you would do so, waste the ressources without much benefit.

I went and checked and there is no 'upper time limit' on how much time a Pokemon can stay in a gym. There has been reports of gyms being held for up to 80-90 days. So it’s not that.

Other option is that some Pokestops were added to the area and what is a Pokestop/gym has been reshuffled. So it’s a gym that is at the same place, but is not the same exact point. But I think usually it will take a Pokestop and make it a gym, but not the other way around.

Comment: I've had pokemon stay for longer than 90 days too, in remote gyms during the winter. And there are some reasons for drive-by battling even if you cannot leave a pokemon behind. Gym badges and research tasks come to mind. Or maybe someone mistimed and their bus arrived (or a raid started!) before they were able to put in their pokemon.

Comment: Lastly a "beneficial" player could have passed by who saw that the gyms are likely not going to be battled anytime soon, so the pokemon in there are essentially useless. He kicked them out to return them to their owner (with some coins), but was not interested in leaving any of his own pokemon behind for what could be an undetermined amount of time.

Comment: Yeah some kind of Pity Kick, when you see a pokemon has been stuck there for weeks and is in red HP state.

Comment: @Vilx: you also gain XP from battling, and get some points towards gold status for the pokegym even if you don't leave a pokemon behind.

Comment: XP, yeah, forgot about that. "Gold status" is what I meant with "gym badges".